# C++ MPL or_, and_ implementations

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I am trying to read the boost headers to figure out how they managed to implement the

```
or_<...>
```

and

```
and_<...>
```

metafunctions so that:

1) They can have an arbitrary number of arguments (ok, say up to 5 arguments)

2) They have short circuit behavior, for example:

```
or_<false_,true_,...>
```

does not instantiate whatever is after true_ (so it can also be declared but not defined)

Unfortunately the pre-processor metaprogramming is making my task impossible for me :P

Thank you in advance for any help/suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how short circuit could work for a three-argument version

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T2>
struct or_ : conditional<T1::value, true_, or<T2, T3>>::type 
{ };
```

That is, if `T1::value` is true, it inherits `true_`, otherwise it inherits `or<T2, T3>`. You need a stop criteria, which works like @begemoth shows: Specialize `or_` for the first type being `none_t`, which will define it's `::value` to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not proficient in Boost.MPL, so I can only guess how it is really implemented, but I have ideas how it could be done.

Let's begin with your first question. This have two solutions one for C++98 (with limited number of arguments) and one for C++0x.
We define `or_` like this:

```
struct null_type { };

template<typename T1 = null_type, typename T2 = null_type, typename T3 = null_type>
struct or_
{
  static const bool value = T1::value || T2::value || T3::value;
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct or_<T1, T2, null_type>
{
  static const bool value = T1::value || T2::value;
};

template<typename T1>
struct or_<T1, null_type, null_type>
{
  static const bool value = T1::value;
};

template<>
struct or_<null_type, null_type, null_type>
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

struct true_ { static const bool value = true; };
struct false_ { static const bool value = false; };
```

To get more parameters for the metafunction you need to specify more parameters for the `or_` template. You can generate specializations using Boost.Preprocessor.

In C++0x you can use variadic templates:

```
template<typename... T>
struct or_;

template<>
struct or_<>
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

template<typename T1, typename... Ts>
struct or_<T1, Ts...>
{
  static const bool value = T1::value || or_<Ts...>::value;
};
```

This classic recursive list processing code. To get familiar with this style read something on functional programming.

The second question is simpler. The `or_` and `and_` metafunctions argument are types i.e. nullary metafunctions and they are called only when their values are needed (this is the semantics of the logical operators in C++). Using simple function the analogous code is:

```
bool true_() { return true; }
bool false_() { return false; }

bool or_(bool (*x)(), bool (*y)()) 
{ 
  return x() || y(); 
}
```

Comment: I do not think the C++98 version would work, as for example or_ with parameters "T1, T2, null_type" would require to instantiate T2::value even if T1::value is true.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I haven't checked the short circuit behaviour.