# Short-circuiting while instantiating template?

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, short-circuiting

Consider this code snippet,

```
template<bool b>
struct other
{
    static const bool value = !b;
};

template<bool b>
struct test
{
    static const bool value = b || other<b>::value;
};

int main()
{
      bool value = test<true>::value;   
}
```

Do compilers instantiate `other<true>` in situations such as the above, when instantiating seems completely unnecessary? Or just because I've written the syntax `other<b>::value`, compilers must instantiate it regardless of the fact that it contributes absolutely nothing to the calculation of the value of `test<true>::value`?

I would like to hear, a) what is *required* by the Standard, and b) what is *actually* implemented by the various compilers? Relevant sections from the Standard would be appreciated.

Comment: According to "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide," page 307, it looks like, at least according to the standard, that no, the compiler will not short-circuit this expression and will indeed evaluate both branches.  I'm not sure exactly why this is or what the more general principle in action here is, but this might be at least a partial answer to your question.

Comment: The Standard doesn't allow them to do "short circuit" here. That's why you need to implement it yourself, as [done here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527706/c-mpl-or-and-implementations/4546727#4546727). The reason is simple: You need to know the type of `other<b>::value` and whether it is convertible to `bool` at all and makes sense. For doing so `other<b>` needs to be instantiated.  What if its type would yield to an overloaded `op||` being called? The initializer would be invalid then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the C++ spec, section $14.7.1/4:

> "A class template specialization is
>   implicitly instantiated if the class
>   type is used in a context that
>   requires a completely-defined object
>   type **or if the completeness of the
>   class type affects the semantics of
>   the program**; in particular, if an
>   expression whose type is a class
>   template specialization is involved in
>   overload resolution"

In the case you illustrated with short-circuiting, the class would have to have a complete type, because you're looking inside of it to find the value static member.  This precludes the compiler from short-circuiting the expression.

As for what actually happens in practice, I'm not sure because I can't see how the compiler could get away with not doing the instantiation.  For example, suppose that the instantiation of `other<b>` looked like this:

```
template <bool B> struct other {
    typedef int value;
};
```

Here, your program would be ill-formed because `other<b>`::value is a type, not a value, but the compiler couldn't diagnose the error without actually doing the instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since the introduction of `constexpr` functions in C++11, you can achieve short-circuiting:

```cpp
template<bool b>
constexpr bool test_other();

template<bool b>
struct test
{
    static const bool value = b || test_other<b>();
};

int main()
{
    bool value = test<true>::value;
}
```

... though `test_other()` is undefined the compiler doesn't attempt to call it.

Unfortunately this doesn't work with `consteval`. In this case the first-level 'test facility' `test` itself must be a function:

```cpp
template<bool b>
consteval bool test_other();

template<bool b>
consteval bool test()
{
    return b || test_other<b>();
};

int main()
{
    bool value = test<true>();
}
```