# How to extract the highest-indexed specialization from a structure?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I'm trying to do some template metaprogramming and I'm finding the need to "extract" the highest index of a specialization of some structure in some type.

For example, if I have some types:

```
struct A
{
    template<unsigned int> struct D;
    template<> struct D<0> { };
};

struct B
{
    template<unsigned int> struct D;
    template<> struct D<0> { };
    template<> struct D<1> { };
};

struct C
{
    template<unsigned int> struct D;
    template<> struct D<0> { };
    template<> struct D<1> { };
    template<> struct D<2> { };
};
```

How can I then write a metafunction like this:

```
template<class T>
struct highest_index
{
    typedef ??? type;
    // could also be:   static size_t const index = ???;
};
```

to give me the highest-indexed `D` that has been specialized inside an arbitrary struct like the ones above, **without** requiring the struct to have declared the count explicitly?

Comment: Let's try a simpler problem first: given a general class template `D<unsigned int>` and a specialization `D<0>`, how are you going to detect at compile time whether `D<N>` is a specialization?

Comment: In other words, how would a type trait `is_specialization_of<S, T>` look like, for general type `T` and specialization `S`?

Comment: I think it is impossible to say that. Because for ANY index `i`, we will always have a valid type `T::D<i>`. Now it is impossible to say `D<i>` is a explicit specialization, or not. Since the type `D<i>` is always valid, we cannot use SFINAE.

Comment: I also don't think this is possible without requiring a specific typedef / index member in the `D` struct, since the idea is that you can't differentiate between a base template and its explicit specializations just like that.

Comment: @Xeo, Nawaz: I can rely on the base template being undefined like in the examples -- would that help, or would it still be impossible?

Comment: @rhalbersma: I don't know that either, I'll try to see if I can figure out a way for that.

Comment: @Mehrdad: That might actually work - you'd just need to recursively SFINAE-check if `D<I+1>` is defined.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't think so, as undefined-ness of struct is caught at the linker time, not at the compile-time. which means that doesn't make any difference, IMO.

Comment: @Xeo: Yup, but *how* do I check if it's defined? (That's what rhalbersma mentioned as well I think.) I'm trying approaches with overloading right now (e.g. `test(...)` and `test(T const &, blah = T::something)`) but I haven't figured out a way yet.

Comment: Do you have a guarantee for *anything* being defined in all specializations? Like, default-ctor or some member function?

Comment: @Xeo: Yeah I can make them all inherit from a class, if that helps. A constructor should also be possible... although there is a default constructor anyway right?

Comment: @Nawaz: Isn't it a compile time issue? Detecting whether a type is defined should be a compile issue...

Comment: @Xeo: On another note, I just came across an interesting bug in VC++... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052579/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope

Comment: @Mehrdad: You're right. I think `sizeof` can help here too. Let me try!

Comment: @Nawaz: Haha okay thanks. :) I'm trying to fix the namespace-level declaration bug now lol... 'cause apparently this example isn't even standard C++.

Comment: [Here](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6bf65f18c218cc1e9bd404687a2b2612)'s a basic mock-up for the SFINAE part. The recursive testing is left as an excercise to the reader. ;) (Note: Divide-and-conquer may help if you know the max index and if it is particularly big.)

Comment: @Xeo: Ooh huh, seems like `enable_if` is a better idea than overloading... cool, lemme try. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the first version which gets you the maximum index for which specialization is defined. From this, you will get the corresponding type!

### Implementation:

```
template<class T>
struct highest_index
{
  private:
     template<int i>
     struct is_defined {};

     template<int i>
     static char f(is_defined<sizeof(typename T::template D<i>)> *);

     template<int i>
     static int f(...);

     template<int i>
     struct get_index;

     template<bool b, int j>
     struct next
     {
        static const int value = get_index<j>::value;
     };
     template<int j>
     struct next<false, j>
     {
        static const int value = j-2;
     };
     template<int i>
     struct get_index
     {
        static const bool exists = sizeof(f<i>(0)) == sizeof(char);
        static const int value = next<exists, i+1>::value;
     };

    public:
     static const int index = get_index<0>::value; 
};
```

### Test code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    template<unsigned int> struct D;
};
template<> struct A::D<0> { };
template<> struct A::D<1> { };

struct B
{
    template<unsigned int> struct D;
};
template<> struct B::D<0> { };
template<> struct B::D<1> { };
template<> struct B::D<2> { };


int main()
{
    std::cout << highest_index<A>::index << std::endl;
    std::cout << highest_index<B>::index << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

[Live demo](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=967fa5954dec31d1d771fdaf304cb6dc). :-)

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm thinking of reducing the size of the implementation. It looks too long! But then I suppose it is easy to read.

Comment: Yours looks a heck of a lot better than mine. :) What's funny is that Visual Studio can't compile either of ours! Apparently it chokes on `sizeof(<invalid-specialization>)`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Realizing that `is_defined` class template, though, adds readability to the code, is not really needed. One could use `char (*) [sizeof(typename T::template D<i>)] ` as parameter type of the function template `f`, like [this](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=29c512ef94f491b1e8eb406bb0b6b870) :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: While it works, I would point out that the complexity is O(N); it will therefore (in all likelihood) fail utterly in the case where `D` is unconstrained or specialized for a wide range of inputs. I think it could be reworked into a binary search to limit the recursion depth.

Comment: @Nawaz: I tried it (in `constexpr` methods), however it's extremely slow; I am afraid that `?:` patterns are not lazily evaluated (ie, both branches are systematically evaluated).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Yes, And  short-circuiting doesn't work with template instantiation also, something like this : [Short-circuiting while instantiating template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600565/short-circuiting-while-instantiating-template)

Comment: @Nawaz: the short-circuiting you refer to speaks of classes, while I have a function here. I expect the compiler to check that both alternatives are correctly typed, but whether it computes the values is different.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I saw your code, and I think *the same* reasoning which Johannes gave in his comment, applies to your case also. He said : *"The Standard doesn't allow them to do "short circuit" here. That's why you need to implement it yourself, as done here. The reason is simple: You need to know the type of `other<b>::value` and whether it is convertible to `bool` at all and makes sense. For doing so `other<b>` needs to be instantiated. What if its type would yield to an overloaded `op||` being called? The initializer would be invalid then."*

Comment: @Nawaz: Thanks to Luc Touraille I finally got a version that binary searches for the value (yeeha), I find it quite unfortunate that I am required to abandon the functional way though...

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out with the help from the comments under the question!

```
struct A { template<unsigned int> struct D; };
template<> struct A::D<0> { };

struct B { template<unsigned int> struct D; };
template<> struct B::D<0> { };
template<> struct B::D<1> { };

struct C { template<unsigned int> struct D; };
template<> struct C::D<0> { };
template<> struct C::D<1> { };
template<> struct C::D<2> { };
template<> struct C::D<3> { };

template<unsigned int>
static unsigned char test(...);

template<unsigned int N, class T>
static typename enable_if<
    sizeof(typename T::template D<N>),
    unsigned char (&)[1 + sizeof(test<N + 1>(T()))]
>::type test(T, typename T::template D<N> = typename T::template D<N>());

int main()
{
    return sizeof(test<0>(C())) - 1;  // Evaluates to number of specializations
}
```

Comment: If C++11 is available, it might be possible to use `constexpr` functions and/or template aliases to ease this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my little contribution.

We start off with the existence methods:

```
template <unsigned>
static unsigned char exists_impl(...);

template <unsigned N, typename T>
static auto exists_impl(T const&&) ->
    typename std::enable_if<sizeof(typename T::template D<N>),
                            unsigned char (&)[2]>::type;

template <typename T, unsigned N>
static constexpr bool exists() {
    return sizeof(exists_impl<N>(std::declval<T>())) != 1;
}
```

I believe here that `constexpr` and function usage do bring a lot to the table in terms of readability, so I don't use the typical types.

Then, we use a typical binary search (2nd attempt, see first attempt at bottom), at a loss of readability, but to benefit from lazy instantiation, we use partial template specialization and `std::conditional`:

```
template <typename T, unsigned low, unsigned high, typename = void>
struct highest_index_in;

template <typename T, unsigned low>
struct highest_index_in<T, low, low>: std::integral_constant<unsigned, low> {};

template <typename T, unsigned low, unsigned high>
struct highest_index_in<T, low, high, typename std::enable_if<(high == low + 1)>::type>:
  std::integral_constant<unsigned, low + exists<T, low+1>()> {};

template <typename T, unsigned low, unsigned high>
struct highest_index_in<T, low, high, typename std::enable_if<(high > low + 1)>::type>:
  std::conditional< exists<T, (low+high)/2>(),
                    highest_index_in<T, (low+high)/2, high>,
                    highest_index_in<T, low, (low+high)/2> >::type
{};

template <typename T>
static constexpr unsigned highest_index() {
   return highest_index_in<T, 0, ~(0u)>::value;
} // highest_index
```

Demo at [liveworkspace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1IiMes%246), computing `highest_index<C>()` is near instantaneous.

---

First attempt at binary search, unfortunately the compiler need instantiate the function bodies recursively (to prove they can be instantiated) and thus the work it has to do is tremendous:

```
template <typename T, unsigned low, unsigned high>
static constexpr auto highest_index_in() ->
   typename std::enable_if<high >= low, unsigned>::type
{
   return low == high                 ? low :
          high == low + 1             ? (exists<T, high>() ? high : low) :
          exists<T, (high + low)/2>() ? highest_index_in<T, (high+low)/2, high>() :
                                        highest_index_in<T, low, (high+low)/2>();
} // highest_index_in

template <typename T>
static constexpr unsigned highest_index() {
   return highest_index_in<T, 0, ~(0u)>();
} // highest_index
```

So, unfortunately, `highest_index` is not usable and the [clang is dang slow](http://liveworkspace.org/code/tTrKx%2412) (not that gcc appears to be doing better).

Comment: I wonder why SFINAE programmers use `char[1]` and `char[2]` or `unsigned char (&)[2]` (as you've used in this case). Wouldn't `char` and `int` work just fine as their sizes are guaranteed to be different?

Comment: Or... your could just make it a class template, which ensures lazy-evaluation (like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8763548/500104)). @Nawaz: `char` and `int` could be the same size. :)

Comment: @Nawaz: I am not sure, I don't think there is a guarantee that `char` and `int` don't have the same size.

Comment: @Xeo: Means `int` could be just `1` byte? How exactly?

Comment: @Nawaz: normally `int` is specified in terms of a minimum range of possible values, while a byte is defined as `sizeof(char)`, thus in theory there is nothing preventing a platform to define 32 bits `char` types.

Comment: @Xeo: I must be missing something, I don't see where the lazy initialization kicks in here. I've asked the question of lazy evaluation of the ternary operator [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213754/may-a-compiler-elide-the-evaluation-of-the-not-taken-branch-in-a-constexpr-fun).

Comment: I think I picked the wrong link, but the point still stands - make it a class template and partially-specialize it on the conditions.

Comment: @LucTouraille: There's `std::conditional`, which is exactly your `if_`. Just as an FYI. :)

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer with a solution using `enable_if`; I don't know if this kind of "heavy" editing is accepted on SO, feel free to revert if you disagree with my initiative.

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks for the reminder, I'm so often disappointed by the lack of metafunctions in the standard library that I keep using Boost.MPL, so I often forget those that were actually included in C++11 :).

Comment: @LucTouraille: Ah thanks, I was actually on my way to that (but stumbled on the `enable_if` trick); I reformatted your code with `std::conditional` and `std::integral_constant` and provided a live-demo on liveworkspace. It works really great now! *Regarding the edit: I don't know either, but I am sure glad you did ;)*