# Should a template be instantiated in short-circuit evaluation?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

I was wondering if the standard has anything to say whether the following code should compile:

```
template <class T> struct Fail
{
    static constexpr bool value = Fail<T>::value;
};

template <class T> struct False
{
    static constexpr bool value = false && Fail<T>::value;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << False<int>::value;
}
```

clang uses short-circuit evaluation and accepts it, GCC tries to instantiate `Fail<T>` and fails.

Comment: Possibly related or duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600565/short-circuiting-while-instantiating-template

Comment: @MarcoA. I think that's a much better dupe. Although, I'm not sure it answers OP's question. It's only a one-directional requirement...

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. Looks like clang is wrong then

Comment: Infinite recursion in template instantiation is UB. Both are conforming.

Comment: @T.C. Indeed you're right! Thank you!